# Drupal hook_menu from module for admin menu

Tags: drupal, module, admin, hook-menu

I have a custom module "menu_mods" for adding menu items to the admin menu. It's not adding it. I want the link to show in the Navigation menu. I'm using the Garland theme for the admin pages.
Here is my module code:

```
function menu_mods_menu() {

    $items = array();

    $items['admin/editfrontpage']=array(
        'title'=>'Edit Homepage',
        'description'=>'Edit Homepage.',
        'page callback' => 'edit_front_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM

    );          
}

function edit_front_page(){
    $frontPageUrl = drupal_get_normal_path(variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node')); // outputs "node/112"
    $frontPageUrl = $frontPageUrl.'/edit';
    drupal_goto($frontPageUrl);
}
```

Any idea why it's not displaying? After I make a change, I go to the modules page and then to the menu page.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

WOW! Silly mistake.
I forgot to return the $items at the end of the function.

return $items;

By the way, this little function gives you an edit link to edit the front page of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the menu cache yet? Not sure if going to the module page does that.

Comment: Yes, I used the Devel module to rebuild menus.